# Angular-loading-bar show progress for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

Is it possible to use angular-loading-bar for showing angular progress on ng-repeat actions (tables).

Loading the data is within a second, the bar is just showed 1 sec (or stalls at 1 sec), displaying the data in the table takes up to 10 seconds (can’t use limitTo).

Is it possible to use angular-loading-bar for progress on ng-repeat or angular specific processing ?

I tried using `ng-init="$first ? cfpLoadingBar.start() : ($last ? cfpLoadingBar.complete() : cfpLoadingBar.inxc())` with ng-repeat but no visual updates are made.

Is there a possibility to have a visual response when angular is 'locked' running ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this should have been a comment, but it wouldn't fit...

No, because as you say, Angular is "locked", so the browser won't render the DOM while processing is happening. In fact, the entire browser tab will seem to freeze. Because this is a terrible user experience in general, I would recommend looking into why your `ng-repeat` is so slow in the first place.

- Did you use [`track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)?
- Can you use [one-time binding](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/) in the individual repeated elements?
- Can you get away with [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to speed up table processing?

Comment: I use angular-datatables especially for searching possibilities on a >1000 array. I have track by and one-time-binding. I have fixed row widths so tried table-layout: fixed, but saw no improvement. Commented above, that I see that the table gets rendered/traversed twice with ng-repeat, any idea?

Comment: Perhaps 1000 table rows is simply too much. Is it performant after `ngRepeat` is done? Did you profile to see why it's still slow? You could consider using a virtual scroll technique.

Comment: Used scrolling it with ui-select but noticed strange issues when filtering and scrolling at the same time. I use anguar-datatables with filtering, therefor the data should be available at once. thx anyway for the hints.

Comment: Still hoping to get some hints to get rid of the progress bar stalling during an ng-repeat.